# How to prevent UIPickerView from closing when the user selects a field?

Tags: ios, iphone, uipickerview

I am trying to prevent my `UIPickerview` from closing when a field is selected by a user. I want the user to be able to select a field without `UIPickerview` dismissing automatically. I have tried so many things such as trying the following but none of them helped:

```
_txtfield.hidden=NO;
[_pickerView endEditing:NO];
[pickerView endEditing:NO];
[_txtfield endEditing:NO];
[self endEditing:NO];
_pickerView.hidden=NO;
```

-----------------Here is more code----------------

```
  @implementation FieldWithPickerView {
    void(^pickerCallback)(NSInteger row);
    CGRect myFrame;


}

-(void)viewDidAppear{

}

-(void)commonInit:(CGRect)frame{



    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:self options:nil];


    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[view]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"view":self.InputViewPicker}]];
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[view]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"view":self.InputViewPicker}]];
    [self.layer setCornerRadius:10.0f];
    [self setClipsToBounds:YES];


    _pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    _pickerView.delegate=self;




    UIToolbar *toolBar=[[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    [toolBar setTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(removePicker)];
    UIBarButtonItem *space=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    [toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:space,doneBtn, nil]];
    [self.txtfield setInputAccessoryView:toolBar];



    self.txtfield.inputView = _pickerView;
    [_txtfield.inputView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [_txtfield setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    _txtfield.text=@"--Select---";


    _label_view.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

    _label_view.backgroundColor=SECURUSBLUE;
    _label_view.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    _txtfield.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;




}
-(void)removePicker
{
    [_txtfield resignFirstResponder];
}

-(void)pickerListenner:(void(^)(NSInteger row))handler
{
    pickerCallback=handler;

}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
//    NSLog(@"initwithframe picker");

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        [self commonInit:frame];

    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Picker View Data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:
(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [_pickerData count];;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
             titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
            forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(_pickerData.count == 0)
        return @"There is nothing";
    return [_pickerData objectAtIndex:row];
}
#pragma mark -

#pragma mark - UIPickerViewDelegate
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    // Code logic
    NSLog(@"selected row --->%ld!!!!",(long)row);
    pickerCallback(row);
//    _txtfield.text=[_pickerData objectAtIndex:row];

    _txtfield.hidden=NO;


}

- (NSInteger)selectedRowInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return component;
}
```

Comment: I think you cant, because you need to display keyboard if textfield is focused.

Comment: can you post the code how you show your picker and how you dismiss it?

Comment: @Vladimir Just posted more code above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the UIPickerView delegate methods, so add `<UIPickerViewDelegate>` to your `ViewController`.

in your `viewDidLoad` method conform to the protocol like so:

```
pickerView.delegate = self;
```

Then add the following method to detect when a row has been selected:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    // do nothing because it will not dismiss
}
```

You will need to implement the `numberOfRowsInComponent`, `numberOfComponents`, and `titleForRow` delegate methods as well, but once those are implemented your picker view should not dismiss when a row is selected.  You will need to manually dismiss the picker view in your `didSelectRow` delegate method.

Comment: I just posted more code above. I did what you are suggesting but my pickerview gets dismiss as soon as selecting a field. Thanks.

Comment: It shouldn't affect the functionality.

Comment: well the built-in functionality of a UIPickerView is that it will NOT dismiss when you select a row, so you are dismissing it somewhere that you should not.  What is your `pickerCallback`

Comment: the callback just pass the row that was selected. I also have this:     self.txtfield.inputView = _pickerView;

Comment: oohhh that changes things, post your textfield code.. are you making another textfield first responder, calling resignFirstResponder, or self.view.endEditing anywhere on the textfields???

Comment: do you click the "done" button on the inputAccessory after you select a row?

Comment: The thing is I want to have the done button there so when i select a field, i press the done and the picker gets dismissed but as soon as i select a field the pickerview gets dismissed.